# NotADirectoryError when converting multiple xml files to .csv

Tags: python

CODE

```
   import os
   import pandas as pd

   df = pd.DataFrame()
   xml_file_path = "/Users/ruzi/Desktop/top1000_complete 2"
   csv_file_path = "/Users/ruzi/Desktop/xml.csv"
   if os.path.isdir(xml_file_path):
       for e in os.listdir(xml_file_path):
           new_path = xml_file_path + "/" + str(e)
           if str(e) != '.DS_Store' and os.path.isdir(new_path):
               for e1 in os.listdir(new_path):
                 next_new_path = new_path + "/" + str(e1)
                 if str(e1) != '.DS_Store' and os.path.isfile(next_new_path):
                    for e2 in os.listdir(next_new_path):
                      third_new_path = new_path + "/" + str(e1)
                      if str(e2) != '.DS_Store' and os.path.isfile(third_new_path):
                      data_frame = pd.read_xml(third_new_path)
                      df=df.append(data_frame)
                      data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
 # Convert Into CSV
   df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=None)
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3     /Users/ruzi/Documents/pythonProject/main.py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/ruzi/Documents/pythonProject/main.py", line 14, in <module>
     for e2 in os.listdir(next_new_path):
     NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/ruzi/Desktop/top1000_complete 2/P04-3022/citing_sentences_annotated.json'

     Process finished with exit code 1
```

[FILE LOCATION][1]

[FOLDER 1][2]

[FOLDER 2][3]

##images
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEeki.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CmnR.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5fVU.png

Answer (score 0):

```
               for e1 in os.listdir(new_path):
                 next_new_path = new_path + "/" + str(e1)
                 if str(e1) != '.DS_Store' and os.path.isfile(next_new_path):
                    # At this point, next_new_path is a file, not a dir
                    for e2 in os.listdir(next_new_path):
```

Consider this file tree:

```
dir1/
    subdir1/
    subdir2/
    file1
    file2
```

e1 is any subpath in new_path (file or directory) (ex. subdir1 or file1)
next_new_path is the same including parent (ex. dir1/subdir1/ or dir1/file)

Then you check that next_new_path is a file (not a dir), so you exclude dir1/subdir/ and only keep dir1/file.

And then you call listdir on this, which is wrong because it is a file, and this is exactly what the error message says.

---

In 2021, I'd recommend using pathlib rather than os.path.

Comment: can u plz edit the code?